# How to create multiple frame in single ADF page and print certain frame only?

Tags: printing, frame, oracle-adf

I got a question.I have ADF form which has print option.When I click the print button, it will print out the whole page.I use this code to pop up new tab to print.

```
     <af:commandButton text="Print" id="cb3">
      <af:showPrintablePageBehavior/>
    </af:commandButton>
```

Is that possible to print only certain part of the form? Can I divide that page into multiple frame and only print only certain frame in ADF? Can anyone show me how to do it?

Need urgently.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Some layout components indeed behave as print boundaries. An easier option that gives you more control of what gets printed is to set the rendered property of components that should not be printed to

rendered ="#{!adfFacesContext.outputMode eq 'printable'}"

If you put this onto the layout containers you don't want to print (including its children) then this should be an easy set up

Frank

Comment: Hi..thanks for the reply...actually what is the difference between rendered ="#{!adfFacesContext.outputMode eq 'printable'}" and rendered="false".
 Because the output look same.Actually i want to hide :                                                 <af:activeImage source="#{resource['images:W9_header.png']}" id="ai1"/> when i click print button only.   

Can i use the same way to hide this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The difference is in the condition. The latter never prints and the first only prints if the output form at is not printable page